# Views with multiple languages

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm building a multi-lingual site with drupal 7.  I see that you can "translate" a page.  How do I translate a view?  The url `http://mysite.com/view` is a view, but I don't see the "translate" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since views are dynamic lists of content, you don't directly translate the view. Rather, you make the view select content of the current user's language. This can be done using the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module, and the [i18n views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module.

Once you have these installed, you add a filter to your view, under the node translation group.

[image]

Comment: The "Content negotiation" was dropped from D7. No more support for this feature :(.

Answer (score 2):

The comment above is correct but, if you are using the [Entity Translation module](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) instead of the core Content Translation module, then you need to use the Advanced / Other language filter instead of the "regular" filter mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you note that some fields have a field and a translated field.

Example: *Taxonomy Term: Name* vs. **Taxonomy Term: Name (translated)** are two totally distinct fields.

The token replacement is even different: *[name]* vs. **[name_i18n]**

I just went through and fixed several views. Wondering if there is a quick fix I could apply to check all views for these kinds of fields... this could take a while.