# views NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR i18n

Tags: views

Is there a way to show different no results behaviors for different languages in views 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/7653/34082)  as there is no way translate the views you just can filter the content of specific language of logged-in user. for enabling translation you check out the [Internationalization Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module.

> Translate views using Internationalization. This is a work in progress and not all Views properties can be translated yet. **Requires [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) 6.x-1.5 or newer**.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this does not answer the question of how to translate the "no results behaviour" - or does it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a current version of i18nviews and ensure that the text format used for the text area is selected as translatable in `/admin/config/regional/i18n/strings`